# Django models.TextChoices vs models.IntegerChoices

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the difference between these two codes?

**Code 1:**

```py
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
    JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
    SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
    GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
```

**Code 2:**

```py
class YearInSchool(models.IntegerChoices):
    FRESHMAN = 1, _('Freshman')
    SOPHOMORE = 2, _('Sophomore')
    JUNIOR = 3, _('Junior')
    SENIOR = 4, _('Senior')
    GRADUATE = 5, _('Graduate')
```

Why does everybody use `models.TextChoices`, although using `models.IntegerChoices` and `models.PositiveSmallIntegerField` will take less memory?

Am I missing something that I am not understanding well?

When to use `models.TextChoices` over `models.IntegerChoices` or vice versa?

I am asking this question because at every django code I am reading, the programmer uses text choices. I am talking generally, even for django versions earlier than 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choices are on the following format:

```
choice_format = (db_format, display_format)
```

The `db_format` is what's saved to the DB.

The `display_format` is what's displayed when you call `get_<FOO>_display`

You basically choose which to save in the DB, the integer or the text choice. The problem is when your model is serialized, if you have field `year` with choices of `YearInSchool(models.IntegerChoices):`, you'll have this:

```
"year": 1
```

in your JSON, but you expect it to show "Freshman", Of course you can manipulate this on the serializer level to show freshman if the `year` is `1`.

`IntegerChoices` are much faster when they are looked up, but the are too ambiguous. If I were you, I'd use IntegerChoices every single time and manipulate the response through the serializer to show the text instead of the integer itself.

Comment: @ahmed-i-elsayed, you don’t need to manipulate the response in through the serializer just use get_<FOO>_display.

Comment: @Abdullah That still is called "manipulate the response"